# How to Unmarshal simple xml with multiple items in Go?

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I would like to get a slice of people ([]People) from the following xml:

```
<file>
    <person>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <age>18</age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Jane Doe</name>
        <age>20</age>
    </person>
</file>
```

(All other similar questions were too specific and verbose)

Comment: Have you _tried_ anything so far? The XML `struct`ure kind of maps onto `struct`s quite easily. You have 1 `struct`ure containing several `person` structures, which you want to map on a slice of `People`type. Why not wrap `[]People` in a `File` type?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes, I tried several things. One thing I tried I also gave as an answer a few hours  before your comment. Is your proposed solution any different to the answer I gave?

Comment: Didn't spot that you authored the answer, it's pretty much what I suggested. Usually not a huge fan of anonymous structs, but when (un)marshalling XML, they have their place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create two structs:

- one to represent the `<file>` `</file>`
- one for the repeating record `<person>` `</person>`

Please see the comments inside the code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

var sourceXML = []byte(`<file>
    <person>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <age>18</age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Jane Doe</name>
        <age>20</age>
    </person>
</file>`)

// Define a structure for each record
type Person struct {
    Name string `xml:"name"`
    Age  int    `xml:"age"`
}

// There needs to be a single struct to unmarshal into
// File acts like that one root struct
type File struct {
    People []Person `xml:"person"`
}

func main() {
    // Initialize an empty struct
    var file File

    err := xml.Unmarshal(sourceXML, &file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    // file.People returns only the []Person rather than the root
    // file struct with it's contents
    fmt.Printf("%+v", file.People)
}
// output:
// [{Name:John Doe Age:18} {Name:Jane Doe Age:20}]
```

Edit. Kaedys said the File and Person structures can also be nested (using anonymous structs) as follows:

```
type File struct {
    People []struct {
        Name string `xml:"name"`
        Age  int    `xml:"age"`
    } `xml:"person"`
}
```

Comment: You don't need these to be separate types.  You can easily include the 'Person' struct as a nested struct directly within the definition of File.  You also should avoid empty literals, `file := File{}` has the exact same effect and is less readable than `var file File` (golint will complain about it, too).  https://play.golang.org/p/pCtSsx7LbZD