# Golang code to create XML with same tag name

Tags: go

I'm trying to create an XML in golang as like below and i'm Beginner to golang please help me to create golang struct for this .
"ContactMech" tag occurred multiple times with diff fields

```
<ns1:ContactMechLst
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.fisglobal.com/services/prepaid/common">
    <ns1:ContactMech>
        <ns1:Telcom>
            <ns1:ContactNumber>+919084258647</ns1:ContactNumber>
        </ns1:Telcom>
    </ns1:ContactMech>
    <ns1:ContactMech>
        <ns1:Email>
            <ns1:EmailType>1</ns1:EmailType>
            <ns1:EAddr>priya@fisglobal.com</ns1:EAddr>
        </ns1:Email>
    </ns1:ContactMech>
    <ns1:ContactMech>
        <ns1:Address>
            <ns1:AddType>1</ns1:AddType>
            <ns1:AddrL1>RK Road</ns1:AddrL1>
            <ns1:AddrL2>Mylapore</ns1:AddrL2>
            <ns1:AddrL3>Chennai</ns1:AddrL3>
            <ns1:city>TamilNadu</ns1:city>
            <ns1:PostCode>600200</ns1:PostCode>
            <ns1:Country>356</ns1:Country>
        </ns1:Address>
        <ns1:Address>
            <ns1:AddType>2</ns1:AddType>
            <ns1:AddrL1>No.22, Sardar Patel Road</ns1:AddrL1>
            <ns1:AddrL2>Guindy</ns1:AddrL2>
            <ns1:AddrL3>Chennai</ns1:AddrL3>
            <ns1:city>TamilNadu</ns1:city>
            <ns1:PostCode>600032</ns1:PostCode>
        </ns1:Address>
    </ns1:ContactMech>
</ns1:ContactMechLst>
```

Comment: Possibly this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53305826/how-to-unmarshal-simple-xml-with-multiple-items-in-go